# Return a pound sign (£) in Django

Tags: django

If i have the following:

```
class PayBand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    lower_limit = models.IntegerField()
    upper_limit = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s (%s - %s)" % (self.name, self.lower_limit, self.upper_limit)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s (%s - %s)' % (self.name, self.lower_limit, self.upper_limit)
```

How would i return a '£' ?

I assumed it would be:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s (£%s - £%s)" % (self.name, self.lower_limit, self.upper_limit)
```

But that didnt work (obviously!), so i tried:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s (&pound;%s - &pound;%s)" % (self.name, self.lower_limit, self.upper_limit)
```

But that didn't work, it just outputted `&pound;`...

Soooo... my question is how do I output a '£' sign as well as the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to answer this well, without seeing how those different methods didn't work, and knowing what you mean by 'output' - do you mean in a template? But here's a couple of possible ways this could have gone wrong.

1. When you tried `&pound;`, did it get escaped? If so, you might need to run `mark_safe` on the string (assuming it is safe!), or use the `|safe` filter in your template.
2. You could try returning a unicode string, with the escaped version of £ in it - that's `u'\xa3'`.

Comment: +1 It sounds like a template issue, so mark_safe is probably the answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you try returning \xc2\xa3 ?

```
>>> str("£")
'\xc2\xa3'
```